# Auxiliary drive belt squeal Ford Fiesta 2013 post facelift

Tags: engine

I drive a Ford Fiesta mk7.5 2013 with the stretchy auxiliary belt, some story behind it but hope someone can help.

I noticed the car squealed when holding certain revs while driving, at exactly the same position regardless of what gear I was in, it was a small squeal but annoyed me in the back of my head while driving, I sprayed dressing spray on it which muted the noise temporarily. It then came back so I decide to purchase a new belt (non genuine) and now whenever I start the car in the cold or wet it screams VERY loud for say 30 seconds until the car has got to its operating temperature, I have tried to diagnose this by seeing if it squeaks with the air con on, turning the air con off and on did make it squeal and stop squealing but then also without the a/c on it would squeal with a large amount of consumers on for example the heated screens, wipers, headlights and radio. Does having a genuine belt affect this? Should I have cleaned the pulleys before putting on the new belt as the dressing could have fouled? Any advice would be appreciated! Would it be good to get a genuine belt clean the pulleys and then place the new genuine belt on?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.. those stretchy belts are a pain - it's a clever enough idea in that it's essentially supposed to be self-tensioning but as you discovered they don't always work properly and can squeak and chirp at certain revs (they also need a special tool to fit!)

From how you describe the symptoms it's almost certainly a case of the belt slipping (causing the squealing) - it would fit as well that the squealing increases as load from the alternator does.

Without knowing what brand of non-OEM belt you bought it's hard to say if that's the cause, I do know they **really** don't like being fitted to non-clean pulleys, and given the prior application of belt dressing it's highly likely that there's a good coating of dirt and general crud on the pulleys since what makes belt dressing work is that it's sticky..and it doesn't discriminate between providing stickiness for the belt and stickiness for dirt.

I'd say your best bet at this point is to take the belt off, make sure the pulleys are all clean and dry and fit a new belt (I wouldn't put the old-new one back on - it'll be covered in crap) and go from there.

Brand-wise I believe the ContiTech ones are quite reasonable and relatively inexpensive, that said the OEM belt isn't insanely expensive on these but I honestly don't think it's going to make any real difference.

Comment: Thank you! I currently have the contitech fitted but when inspecting the pulleys I did find quite a lot of dirt and sticky residue left on them! I will surely go forward with that idea of replacing and cleaning and hopefully it works!

Comment: @OliverHerrero yeah that dirt etc is going to play havoc with the belts traction, especially when it's cold or load is high. Fortunately the belts aren't that costly but they are enough of a PITA to fit that it's not a job you want to be doing twice in quick succession! Hope it resolves it for you this time :)